# Blur if something changed in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of text boxes with a class called "dimensions"

In my JS I have

```
$('.dimensions').blur(function () {
DoSomething();
```

It's working as i want so it does something when i tab through any of the text boxes,
However I only really want it to do something if the value changed from the text box im tabbing out from. (ie theres no need to  `DoSomething()` as the input didn't change in cases where im just tabbing through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres how i did it

```
     var currentVal;
        $('.dimensions').focus(function () {
            currentVal = $(this).val();

        });

      $('.dimensions').blur(function () {

            if ($(this).val() == currentVal) {
                return false;
            }
           //DoSomething();

    });
```

Not sure what the downvotes were for!

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to use [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event in this context.

```
$('.dimensions').change(DoSomething);
```

Comment: does this work for textboxes? as it doesnt seem to hit this in firebug

Answer (score 0):

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3uxY/)
you may use following

```
$('.dimensions').bind('input', function() {
    /* This will be fired every time, when textbox's value changes. */
} );
```